# I'm trying to create and call a PHP function that uses multiple statements

Tags: php, arrays, function, call

I'm writing an NPC generator for use with D&D 3.5, and I've gotten the kinds of results I want by "randomly" sampling various PHP arrays using

```
print_r(array_rand($a,1));
```

The whole bit which generates an NPC is of that style, with arrays labeled $a through $e. A result from my code comes out like this (array labels added for a little clarification)

```
($a)Half-Orc ($b)male: ($c)Young, ($d)with a relaxed, peaceful disposition 
($e)and some items that need to be fetched/located.
```

My problem is that I can't figure out exactly how to make a block of these statements into a function which can be called. I've tried using

```
function Generator(){
print_r(array_rand($a,1));
print_r(array_rand($b,1));
print_r(array_rand($c,1));
print_r(array_rand($d,1));
print_r(array_rand($e,1));
}
```

But it's gotten me nowhere when I try to call it using

```
Generator();
```

Am I just being stupid, or is there something I'm seriously missing?

Comment: why all of your statements are out side of your function {} ?? you should put } after all your print_r statements!!

Comment: I made a mistake in writing it here. The statements are inside the braces.

Answer (score 0):

A function/method consists of the statements inside the braces (in this case none) What you probably mean to do is put the `print_r` statements *inside* the function;

```
function Generator(){
    print_r(array_rand($a,1));
    print_r(array_rand($b,1));
    print_r(array_rand($c,1));
    print_r(array_rand($d,1));
    print_r(array_rand($e,1));
}
```

Also, unless `$a`-`$e` are global variables, you'll want to pass them in as parameters;

```
function Generator($a, $b, $c, $d, $e){
    print_r(array_rand($a,1));
    print_r(array_rand($b,1));
    print_r(array_rand($c,1));
    print_r(array_rand($d,1));
    print_r(array_rand($e,1));
}
```

...and call it using;

```
Generator($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I mistyped earlier--those print_r statements are inside the curly braces. But the rest is news to me. Thanks again!